# How to remove exception from headers in Okhttp

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I am making an authorized call from the using token. Firstly the user gets a token after sign in, I stores that token in shared preferences, and passed that token(stored as string) as header to retrofit api call using okhttp as client. Now getting this error. How to encode the header/ token or remove this error.
[example of token I get from API : "Du_jwJP64Znbwc1EvyJMEkw9HHwIZPjYnXgchiq5e2Tf24y9vNBrD6PJX8jTMj7qGDQyxTDBW8XrlwSRBjNQ-Tzzafq7r3jS5x9ZsXJgU9JgDi8ZNmwf_JD47aTRUKEhX5KtZ52oOeiuOnjO9XKCKT2g1vLpmcpUxvOi36R6ySNoMBmWzn7KmG6_vZzhfT0YhhfIW8x6vPEHmDLvBIIWbBDry0qpoiZNkgkI2D6CkFqQN1Hy-fMc3tFX7Y-VPRBF6bXQOHbsDAPkSqFfVxMQaw "]
API service interface :

```html
@FormUrlEncoded @Multipart @POST("api/user/info") @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"}) Call
<QRcodeResponse> getUserinfo(@Header("Authorization") String Auth);
```

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x20 at 12 in header name: Content-Type 
    at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:330)
    at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:288)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseHeaders(ServiceMethod.java:329)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseMethodAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:270)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:175)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy0.getUserinfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.two_locally.sign_in.updateContent(sign_in.java:209)
    at com.example.two_locally.sign_in.access$000(sign_in.java:45)
    at com.example.two_locally.sign_in$3.onResponse(sign_in.java:160)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space in your `@Header` annotation on your service interface.

Comment: @POST("api/user/info")
    @Headers({"Content-Type : application/json"})
    Call<QRcodeResponse> getUserinfo(@Header("Authorization") String Auth);

Comment: Thanks it works now, got another error, only one annotation is allowed